# HSQLDB:user lacks previlige or object not found

Tags: hsqldb

I created a table in HSQLDB, but when I insert any value into the table I am getting the following error:

`user lacks previlige or object not found`.

My column names are `username` and `password`. This is HSQL Database Engine In-Memory. The driver is `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` and the url is `jdbc:hsqldb:mem`. What did I do wrong, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please show the CREATE TABLE and SELECT statements that you use.

Comment: create table login (username varchar(255),password varchar(255));

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly creating the table in one Java process and inserting the values in another Java process.

The short answer is: use an HSQLDB server for the database and connect to the server from your different processes.

See the Guide on how to run a server.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_hsql_server

There are also HowTo pages at http://hsqldb.org